# Java: How can I create method that works on my date class

Tags: java, date

I have a date class and it has the following

```
public class Date {
    public int month;
    public int day;
    public int year;

    public Date(int m, int d, int y)
    {
        month = m;
        day = d;
        year = y;
    }
    public Date increase(int numberOfDays)
    {
        day += numberOfDays;
        return this;
    }
```

My question is what is the easiest way to do increasing of number of days to that given instance of Date? Like for example I have a created an instance of new Date(4,20,2016).increase(30); which would increase the given date addition 30 days. That would be sometime in May 19 I think. The method above should work if it's less than the max day of the month. But I haven't figure out how to do the calculation including the month and year. Like I added 365 days to that date would be 4/20/2017. Just an idea would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: the answers to this are to use the Calendar class which is probably your best bet but if you insist on using your 'Date' class you need to have a check to see which months have '28,29,30,31' days then if the 'day' variable is greater than however many days this month has set it to 1 and increase the month counter. If the month counter is greater than 12 increase the year and set month to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Java `Calendar` object instead. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: I know that Java provides a Calendar class but I wish to have my own since I have additional methods that Java doesn't have in their class. But thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Then I would write a wrapper around the `Calendar` class and implement the additional methods you need.

Comment: Oh yeah. Never thought of that! Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem glad to help.

Comment: FYI the .Calendar class has been supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later, with back-ports to Java 6 & 7 and to Android.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new Date(); 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30); // add 30 days
date = cal.getTime();
```

using jcalendar you can add the dates try this example

Answer (score 1):

Implementing this yourself is a suprisingly tricky task. More so since you are storing your `Date` as a separate `month`, `year` and `day`. You would have to store information about the number of days in every month, along with information about leap years. In short, trying to re-implement `Date` is not easy.

One solution to storing a "day, month, year" date before Java 8 came along was to use [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Using Joda's `LocalDate` class, you can do:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
date = date.plusDays(30);
```

This functionality is now available in Java 8's `java.time` package, using the same `LocalDate` class name. Take a look at the source code for either package to see how it's implemented.

In short, `LocalDate.plusDays()` first converts the "month, day, year" date to a single number of days since the "epoch", using an algorithm that's around twenty lines long. Then, it adds the requested number of days to that number. Finally, it converts that number back to a "day, month, year" using another algorithm that's even longer.

Comment: Good answer, but I would suggest always passing a time zone to the `now()` method. If omitted your JVM’s current default time zone is applied silently. Better to specify your expected/desired time zone.